# Nodejs - svg file is being displayed as xml

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg

Within my script, i'm downloading the badge from badge.io using https.get and then pipe the response. Example Url: https://img.shields.io/badge/aa-sta-brightgreen.svg

What happen is when i try to display that downloaded svg, it's being interpreted as xml. Ie: when i try to display it on localhost, i have this message:
"This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."

However, if i downloaded the svg as txt extension, then rename it to svg extension then it is being displayed correctly, without the above error message.

Here is my download function:

```
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
  var request = https.get(url, function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
  }).on('error', function(err) { 
    fs.unlink(dest); 
    if (cb) cb(err.message);
  });
```

is it anyway to download the svg and displayed it directly on localhost instead of changing its extension? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the response's content-type?

res.setHeader("Content-type","image/svg+xml");

Comment: thanks, but i still have the xml warning message. The svg file is not displayed as expected